# Scala implicits exercises

Tags: scala

I am working on the exercises from https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/implicits

For the following question, my answer seems incorrect but I do not know why.

```
object MyPredef {

  class KoanIntWrapper(val original: Int) {
    def isOdd = original % 2 != 0

    def isEven = !isOdd
  }

  implicit def thisMethodNameIsIrrelevant(value: Int) =
    new KoanIntWrapper(value)
}

import MyPredef._
//imported implicits come into effect within this scope
19.isOdd should be(true) //my answer but it seem incorrect
)
20.isOdd should be(false)  //my answer but it seem incorrect
```

The error is `There was a problem evaluating your answer, please try again later.`

Comment: Please ignore this question. The problem occurred because my session had timed out.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answers are `true` and `false` correspondingly, so your answers are correct.

You have extra closing bracket:

```
19.isOdd should be(true) //my answer but it seem incorrect
)  // <-- HERE
20.isOdd should be(false)  //my answer but it seem incorrect
```

Good luck with learning Scala.

---

Right now checked this exercise, everything works. So it seems it was some temporary issue.

[image]